# Python if a loop produces same output string for each iteration, how to print only once?

Tags: python, if-statement, output

```
a = [['jimmy', '25', 'pancakes'], ['tom', '23', 'brownies'], ['harry', '21', 'cookies']]
for i in range(len(a)):
    if (a[i][1] == '20' or a[i][1] == '26'):
        print 'yes'
    else:
        print 'Not found'
```

This output's `Not found` three times. If the output of the every iteration of the if loop is the same, I want it to iterate over the entire list and then print `Not found` only once.

If I change `a[i][1] == '25'` and the output becomes:

```
yes
Not found
Not found
```

I want to print `yes` but not `Not found`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

may be you're looking for `for-else` loop.

and as @Burhan Khalid suggested use `for i in a` instead if `range(len(a))`:

```
a = [['jimmy', '25', 'pancakes'], ['tom', '23', 'brownies'], ['harry', '21', 'cookies']]
for i in a:
    if (i[1] == '25' or i[1] == '26'):
        print 'yes'
else:
    print 'Not found'
```

**output:**

```
yes
Not found
```

Or may be you're looking for `any()`:

```
In [200]: if any((i[1]=='25' or i[1]=='26') for i in a):
    print 'yes'
else:    
    print 'not Found'
   .....: 


yes

In [204]: if any((i[1]=='20' or i[1]=='26') for i in a):
    print 'yes'
else:    
    print 'not Found'
   .....: 


not Found
```

Comment: `range(len(a))` can be better setup as `for i in a:`, then `if i[1] == '25 or i[1] == '26':`

Comment: Thanks! It solves the first problem. But it still print `Not found` once for the second problem. How do I get it to print only `yes` for positive matches and nothing for negative matches?

Comment: print nothing for the negative matches , then why do you want to print `Not Found`?

Comment: @koogee see my edited answer may be that is what you were looking for.